# How do I get my Human and Computer player to take turns in Connect4 game?

Tags: java, eclipse, oop

I have just implemented a player interface in order to make my program more object oriented. The game has a computer player and a human player, both of which implement from the player interface.

However, how do I make sure that the Human and the Computer take it in turns to play on my main method? If i run this code currently, it only allows player 1 to play until theyve won, then moves onto the computer.

Comment: Instead of putting the game loop `while(true)` in getUserInput, put it in your main function

Comment: How would i structure the while true in main?

Comment: If i take while our of getuserinput then it breaks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move your game loop `while` in your main function, otherwise it is waiting for the game to end in `HumanPlayer.getUserInput()`. Also, you should add a function that verifies if either player has won, because it doesn't match the definition of `getUserInput`.

```
HumanPlayer human = new HumanPlayer();
ComputerPlayer computer = new ComputerPlayer();

while(!human.hasWon() && !computer.hasWon()) { // Remove the loop from getUserInput() !!!
     human.getUserInput();
     computer.getUserInput();
}
```

The function `public boolean hasWon()` should be defined in `Player` and overriden in `HumanPlayer` and `ComputerPlayer` to math the code you already have that verifies if they won.

---

Please let me know if you have any other concern.

Comment: Thank you for your help Paul, really appreciate it. What should hasWon look like in player?

Comment: `public boolean hasWon();`. Then override it in `HumanPlayer` and `ComputerPlayer`, I didn't look deep into your algorithm but it seems the condition should be `if(Connect4.placeCounter(boardColumn, 1)) return true;`. You'd want to make `boardColumn` a class variable so you can access it from the function.

Comment: Im sorry paul, im getting confused. Do you think you could restructure my code to show me how this works? I really appreciate your help, but every time i change something in my code it breaks something elsewhere. i am so close to finishing this project and this is the last step so would really appreciate the help

Comment: https://pastebin.com/8ARrzruT - Let me know if that works. If you have any question on the code let me know.

Comment: Paul you beautiful man! It works, however the only thing that is strange is that when i start the game, it puts two counters in in the first column automatically. Why is this? see edit for image

Comment: replace the while loop in main by a do...while loop: https://pastebin.com/ckm1nNmF. This happened because of `placeCounter()` in `hasWon`, which was triggered when entering the game loop. It's not needed but you might want to put placeCounter() out of hasWon() because it doesn't make much sense for the hasWon() function to place the pieces. And thanks, everyone is beautiful :)

Answer (score 3):

I took a different approach, and added my code to a public github repo. In Summary, I created objects for BoardPositions, created an Interface for Player with two classes that implement it, Human Player and Computer Player. The Player interface has a method makeMove() and in the human player implementation it will sysout, sysin to get the value. For the Computer Player I created a abstract class called ComputerStrategy, that allows multiple computer strategies to be implemented and the computer player makeMove method delegates to the strategy. I also created a GameController that is instantiated in the Main method of the Main class and it allows you to setup the game by asking how many human players (then the name of each human player) and how many computer players. I also made each human player pick a unique character that represents their pieces on the board.

Its not fully implemented, the logic that checks for a winner needs to be added, the controller also randomizes the player order and it needs a loop to for player turns until the game board is full with no winner or a winner is found.

For the computer strategies, my idea was to start simple by just blocking any potential winning move, I made ComputerStrategy an abstract class because it should have helper methods like if there is a potential next winning move and if so return the column.

This is probably different than you'd think of, but if you get anything out of it upvote my answer :)

GitHubRepo https://github.com/krebznet/connect4.git

P.S
Here is the Output in its current state a bit buggy with a dumb computer strategy but the controller works.

[image]

Comment: Interesting Duncan - I really like the way this is set out! Thank you so much for your response, people like you deserve a knight hood

Comment: Thanks :) I added the console output to the answer, needs work to get the bugs out, but like the idea of having initials for game positions of the player and digits for the computer

Comment: Keeping it object oriented and thinking outside the box!